# Binding v-model inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array of objects, which i need to pass to child component via `v-for` to process in. Child component must tell the parent component that its data was changed; I tried to do it this way:

Parent component:

```
<template>
<row
  v-for="(calc, index) in calculators"
  :key="index">
    <child-component v-model:calc="calculators[index]"></child-component>
</row>
<button @click="addCalculator"
</template>
<script>
....
data() {
  return {
    calculators: [
      {
        "name":"some name",
        ..
      },
      {
        "name":"some name 2",
        ..
      }
    ]
  }
},
methods: {
  addCalculator() {
    this.calculators.push(someDefaultCalculatorObject)
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
<input v-model="calc.name"/>
</template>
<script>
...
props: {
  calc:Object
},
setup(props) {
  const calc = ref(props.calc)
  return calc
},
watch: {
  calc: {
    handler(val) {
      this.$emit('update:calc', val)
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
</script>
```

But when i'm trying to edit value of input of one object, every object in array updating to this value. How can i bind objects in array inside v-for?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-v-model-inside-the-v-for-loop-in-order-to-access-a-current-object/7764 ?

Comment: v-model seems ok. Are you sure you are not passing same object on multiple indexes like `let a={}, b={}, c = [a, b, b, b, b]`?

Comment: About https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-v-model-inside-the-v-for-loop-in-order-to-access-a-current-object/7764/10: i see there is solutions only about straight v-model, not v-model:someProp

Comment: Dimava: generally i'm pushing in array default object which is described in `const`, may it cause that every object in array is just reffering to this constant? I thought that when i'm using `push`, new element of array is not related to this constant

Comment: Oh. Now i see problem. When i'm pushing object in array, actually array contains a shallow copy. So when i'm changing one of pushed objects, i'm changing a default object template. Thank you!